# How to constrain echo state to the current batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I used to think that `setlocal` would create a new scope such that `echo on/off` would not leak to the calling script.

Given `foo.cmd`:

```
@setlocal
@echo off

echo %0:A
echo

call bar.cmd
@REM cmd /c bar.cmd

echo %0:B
echo
```

and `bar.cmd`:

```
bar.cmd
@setlocal
@echo on

echo %0:C
echo
```

Then run `foo.cmd`:

```
D:\src>foo.cmd
foo.cmd:A
ECHO is off.

D:\src>echo bar.cmd:C
bar.cmd:C

D:\src>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\src>echo foo.cmd:B
foo.cmd:B

D:\src>echo
ECHO is on.
```

Switching from `call` to `cmd /c` gets the desired behavior, but I want a way to write `bar.cmd` that doesn't modify the caller's echo status even when called with `call`.

Would love both deeper explanation and suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at [Was ECHO ON or OFF when my Windows .bat was CALLed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48420074/463115)

Comment: The `echo` status is a property of the active cmd.exe process, so it is preserved through all called (and returned) subroutines. The execution of a new cmd.exe resets the echo to On. You could easily set the default On status to Off via a simple modification in the cmd.exe file, but surely you want NOT to do it!!! **`:(`**

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line

```
@FOR /f "tokens=3delims=. " %%s IN ('echo') DO @ECHO subprocedure entry state is %%s
```

You would find that this reports the `echo` state to be `ON`, regardless of the caller's `echo` state or whether this line is the first line of the subprocedure or whether it follows the `@setlocal` line.

I'd therefore adjudge detecting the caller's state to not be possible using this method, but

```
echo>filename
```

will generate a file containing the `echo` status, so

**main procedure q78090799.bat **

```
@SETLOCAL
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%s IN (OFF ON) DO FOR %%u IN (OFF ON) DO @(

 @ECHO %0:%%s
 @ECHO %%s
 @ECHO
 @ECHO calling subprocedure with ECHO state %%s; s/p %%u
 @CALL q78090799_2 %%u
 @ECHO
 @ECHO ===============================================
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**sub procedure q78090799_2.bat**

```
@SETLOCAL
@echo>"%temp%\#$"&FOR %%e IN ("%temp%\#$") DO @(IF %%~ze==13 (SET "echostate=on") ELSE (SET "echostate=off"))&@DEL "%temp%\#$"
@ECHO %1
@echo %0 runs with echo state %1
rem on exit, restore original state
@ECHO %echostate%
@GOTO :EOF
```

Should restore the original state, using the local variable `echostate` and its being critical that the `@ECHO %echostate%` is executed on exiting the subprocedure.